# Mobile emulator/simulator Detox screenshot artifacts differ when run on different hosts

Tags: android, ios, circleci, libpng, detox

I'm taking screenshots with Detox locally and committing them to my source repo. In continuous integration (Circle/macOS executor), I'm running the test again and detecting any file differences. Basically a form of visual regression testing. Unexpectedly, the PNG files differ when run on CI. This is occurring for both iOS and Android. Inspecting the resulting PNG file that was run on CI, the RGB values differ randomly by one. For example RGB(23,42,23) vs RGB(23,42,24). The difference could be in any of the color channels. Spot checking the result, it's usually just one channel (but presumably could be more than one).

Some notes:

- For Android, it looks like the `adb screencap` command is used by Detox, which looks like it can emit raw or PNG output (Detox is using the latter).
- The same emulator (Android) and simulator (iOS) type is being used in the tests

So my questions are:

- Is PNG output deterministic given the same input?
- Is `adb screencap` (and the equivalent on iOS used by Detox) causing this?

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior, and will happen on iOS as well.

For example, see this issue of a similar problem:
https://github.com/uber/ios-snapshot-test-case/issues/109

Differences in OS, CPU and GPU hardware all contribute to slight differences in rendering, which you can attempt to counter by allowing some leeway in comparison tolerance, but that is by no means a silver bullet and will not always be possible.

In my view, screenshot comparison is not a good idea and will introduce a lot of flakiness to your tests.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit about why you feel negatively about screenshot comparison? If the screenshots are identical, shouldn't there be no reason for flakiness?

For context, I am a web developer and not a mobile developer, so there may be something I misunderstand about mobile. On the web, screenshot comparison via DOM (ie. Percy) has performed very effectively for me, but that has some clear stability advantages over a raw snapshot.

Comment: Even if you ignore the hardware rendering issue you are experiencing, screenshot comparison relies on too many systems to work. iOS/Android layout system and look, RN layout and look, etc. It will be very difficult for you to get it to work consistently.